# C - Why is fp == NULL true after fopen(filename, "r")?

Tags: c, file, null, fopen

I am trying to read the number of lines of a file in Ubuntu. For my code I'm using CodeBlocks.

This is the code I've made.

```
int countlines()
{
  // count the number of lines in the file called filename
  FILE *fp = fopen("words", "r");
  int ch=0;
  int lines=0;

  if (fp == NULL){
    return 0;
  }

  lines++;
  while(!feof(fp))
  {
    ch = fgetc(fp);
    if(ch == '\n')
    {
        lines++;
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return lines;
}
```

If I call countlines(), the return value is a 0, that is because he checks if fp==NULL, and that is true.

I placed words in the same folder as my main. The executable file is in Projectfolder/bin/Debug.

Words looks like this:

```
"albatros",
"olifant",
"kantklos",
"robijn",
"internet"
```

The final goal is to fill an array with the words of the file words, without using #include "words".

Comment: May be the file was not found, may be you don't have read access, check for the problem using [stat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html).

Comment: That's why you should say ; `if (fp == NULL) { perror("Ups"); return -1; }` (`perror` gives you a reason, and `-1` or other negative value is OK way to signal to called the function failed.)

Comment: it's words. i have the permission to read the file

Comment: And what does `perror()` say? *“No such file or directory”*?

Comment: @Morpfh Ups: No such file or directory, so yes

Comment: @Morpfh I now have FILE *fp = fopen("Documents/Projects/OS/OS4/words","r"); but still Ups: No such file or directory

Comment: @Jasper: Hmm. Installed Codeblocks, and it runs from *Projectfolder* here, as such it should find it by `fopen("words", "r")`. You could use absolute path, or try to open a file for write. E.g. `fopen("testfile123", "w")`, run the program and then search for the file *testfile123* to find out where it was stored. At least here it get stored in same path as `main.c`, and opening works fine with `fopen("words", "r")`. Can be there are some config in CB that messes up which path the program is run from.

Comment: @Morpfh it stores in the Debug folder (~/bin/Debug), so if I read from ../../words, it should work right?

Comment: Yes, if words is at `~/words`

Comment: If you look at (menu) `Project->Properties...->[Build targets]` and look at *Execution working dir* you should be able to set what directory the program is run from. Note that there are likely at least two Build targets: *Debug* and *Release*.

Comment: if I use ~/words he says no such file or directory, and if I say ../../words, it goes on. but my program is a little complicated, I have to edit a hangman program to let it be played with multiple players. that's something i've done, and I have to read the words from the file, without using include. I actually can't use printlines because it won't display them.

Comment: Execution working dir is now ".", and Objects output dir is "obj/Debug/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what the working directory is set to. It might not be pjt/bin/Debug. Also, try specifying full path to the file.

Comment: to open the project, I have to follow the next steps in my terminal. \n
cd Documents/Projects/OS/OS4/bin/Debug \n
./OS4 & \n
telnet localhost 1066

Comment: @Jasper, It looks like in Code Blocks the working directory is the to the path of the project file. You can change that. Go to **"Project -> Properties -> Build targets -> [name of target] -> Execution working dir"** and set it to .../bin/Debug

Answer (score -1):

```
if (fp == NULL){
    return 0;
  }
```

fp is checked with NULL, because, `fopen` returns pointer, if it succeed, it will be non-NULL, so if `fp == NULL`, then file open does not succeed. That's why program cannot proceed, and just return.

Comment: While everything stated in this answer is correct, it is completely useless, because it does not explain *why* `fopen()` might return `NULL` in this case.